# Old Tweepy's (set_request_token) function

Tags: django

I'm using the DjTweepy model to run tweepy + django together, all went fine until I tried the callback function:

```
def callback(request):
verifier = request.GET.get('oauth_verifier')
oauth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
token = request.session.get('unauthed_token_tw', None)
# remove the request token now we don't need it
request.session.delete('unauthed_token_tw')
oauth.set_request_token(token[0], token[1])   

# get the access token and store

try:
    oauth.get_access_token(verifier)
except tweepy.TweepError:
    print ('Error, failed to get access token!!!!')
request.session['access_key_tw'] = oauth.access_token.key
request.session['access_secret_tw'] = oauth.access_token.secret
response = HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('info'))
return response
```

I believe the statement: **oauth.set_request_token(token[0], token[1])**  is from the old version of Tweepy: http://sourcecodebrowser.com/jsonbot/0.80.3/classjsb_1_1contrib_1_1tweepy_1_1auth_1_1_o_auth_handler.html#adcac2093309df3a93dd95f9c2c3c91a9

I'm not sure whether it is useful now or not, keeping it results (of course):
**'OAuthHandler' object has no attribute 'set_request_token'**
removing it would result:
 **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'**

What should be done? 
Thanks

Comment: I do R&D an it works for me answered

Answer (score 2):

Here it is bit confusing in docs also. I have get worked with tweepy 3.3.0 it works as follows.

```
    oauth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)
    oauth.request_token = {'oauth_token': request.args.get('oauth_token') ,'oauth_token_secret': request.args.get('oauth_verifier') }
    get_token = oauth.get_access_token(request.args.get('oauth_verifier'))
    api = tweepy.API(oauth)
    #api.update_status('tweepy + oauth!here Is sparta')
    public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
```

Here **token = session.get('request_token')** is nothing but *'oauth_token'* and
**auth.request_token = token** here need to set an dict *{'oauth_token': request.args.get('oauth_token') ,'oauth_token_secret': request.args.get('oauth_verifier') }*

and it works fine!.